# Error in update query in c# for access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am facing error in following Query.According to my knowledge I have written everything perfectly fine. But its giving error that:

> "there is an error in update query"

```
string insert_query = "update aho set read=?,pick=? where Cont_no='" + contract_no + "'";
OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand();
ocmd.CommandText = insert_query;
//ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrct_no", contract.Text.ToString());
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@read_val", Convert.ToInt32(read.Text));
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic_val", Convert.ToInt32(pick.Text));
ocmd.Connection = conn;
ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is your `insert_query` looks like when you debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't gave us too much information but..

I think your `Cont_no` type is some numerical type, not one of the character type. Looks like that's why you get error when you try to add it with `''`.

For example like;

```
Cont_no = '123'
```

Try this one;

```
string insert_query = "update aho set [read]=?,pick=? where Cont_no=?";
OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand();
ocmd.CommandText = insert_query;
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@read_val", Convert.ToInt32(read.Text));
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic_val", Convert.ToInt32(pick.Text));
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrct_no", contract_no);
ocmd.Connection = conn;
ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**EDIT**:  HansUp is [totally right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706482/error-in-update-query-in-c-sharp-for-access-database/19706767?noredirect=1#comment29275585_19706767). `Read` is a [`reserved keyword`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm). You should use it with square brackets like `[Read]` in your query.

Comment: Cont_no is string. and your provided solution is still not working

Comment: @user2927881 What is your `insert_query` looks like when you debug it?

Comment: @user2927881 I'm not asking exception. I'm asking when you look at `insert_query` in debugger, what you see ?

Comment: i have put break points but its not taking me to debugger and poping up the exception.

Comment: @user2927881 Put full of your stacktrace. (Full detailed exception message)

Comment: `Read` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#R).  Bracket it in the statement ... `set [read]=?`

Comment: @user2927881 I updated my answer based on HansUp comment. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your query string you consider parameters by priority, but when you create them you are giving them a name.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx, OleDbCommand does not support named parameters.

Look at this example (source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/PassparametertoOleDbCommand.htm):

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    public class Prepare {    
     public static void Main () { 
       String connect = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source=.\\Employee.mdb";
       OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect);
       con.Open();  
       Console.WriteLine("Made the connection to the database");

       OleDbCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
       cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Employee "
                        + "WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?";
       OleDbParameter p1 = new OleDbParameter();
       OleDbParameter p2 = new OleDbParameter();
       cmd1.Parameters.Add(p1);
       cmd1.Parameters.Add(p2);
       p1.Value = "01";
       p2.Value = "03";
       OleDbDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
       while(reader.Read()) 
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetInt32(0));
       reader.Close();
       con.Close();
     }
    }
```

Comment: when i am doing it with priority order.its still not working.